# CXF TLSClientParameters setDisableCNCheck true does not work

Tags: cxf

I am using CXF 2.7.3 and want to disable CN checking in code with:

```
TLSClientParameters tlsParams = conduit.getTlsClientParameters();
if (tlsParams == null) {
    tlsParams = new TLSClientParameters();
}
tlsParams.setSecureSocketProtocol(sslAlgorithm);
tlsParams.setUseHttpsURLConnectionDefaultHostnameVerifier(false);
tlsParams.setDisableCNCheck(true);
```

It does not seem to work for me. I've tried all kinds of examples from the WEB with no luck.
If I use cxf.xml it works with this:

```
<http-conf:conduit name="*.http-conduit"
    xmlns:sec="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security"
    xmlns="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration">
    <http-conf:tlsClientParameters disableCNCheck="true" useHttpsURLConnectionDefaultHostnameVerifier="false" />
</http-conf:conduit>
```

I would rather not pull in Spring config just to get this one-liner to work.
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am really not sure it will solve your problem (not enough information and I don't have enough reputation to make comments on your post :-)) but since I spent days on a similar problem it won't hurt to make the info public...

I ran into a similar problem when adding interceptors.
If you call  `client.getEndpoint();`
at some point in your code the conduit will be reinitialized, cf

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cxf-users/201305.mbox/%3COFB00B58DA.85E410E4-ONC1257B6D

The solution was to write a custom interceptor that does the client/conduit configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Old topic, but I'll mark the solution in case anyone has this same error...

After set the **tlsParams.setDisableCNCheck(true);**,  you must set the  TLSClientParameters into the conduit **conduit.setTlsClientParameters(tlsParams );**